# Add Parent Id toEvery Nested Child in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to create a parent id and insert that Id into every nested child of Object.
I have tried this:

```js
const data = {
  values:[
    {
      name:"test1",
      validation:"",
      values:[{
        name:"nested1",
        validation:"",
        values:[{
          name:"nested2",
          validation:""
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      name:"test21",
      validation:"N/A",
      values:[{
        name:"nested",
        validation:""
      }]
    }
  ]
}

const iterate = function(value, parentVal){
  value.forEach((ele,idx) => {
    ele.parent = `${parentVal}${idx}`;
    if(ele.values && ele.values.length > 0){
      if(typeof ele.values === "object"){
        parentVal = idx;
        iterate(ele.values, parentVal)
      }
    }
  })
  return value
}

iterate(data.values,0)
```

what i m trying to do add parent reference to every child, like for example `data.values[0].values[0].values[0]` i want to add parent refrence parentVal as 000, and for `data.values[0].values[0]`  parentval 0.

Answer (score 0):

Changing nested call to `iterate(ele.values, ele.parent)` instead of `iterate(ele.values, parentVal)` should be fine.

```js
const data = {
  values:[
    {
      name:"test1",
      validation:"",
      values:[{
        name:"nested1",
        validation:"",
        values:[{
          name:"nested2",
          validation:""
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      name:"test21",
      validation:"N/A",
      values:[{
        name:"nested",
        validation:""
      }]
    }
  ]
}

const iterate = function(value, parentVal){
  value.forEach((ele,idx) => {
    ele.parent = `${parentVal}${idx}`;
    if(ele.values && ele.values.length > 0){
      if(typeof ele.values === "object"){
        parentVal = idx;
        iterate(ele.values, ele.parent)
      }
    }
  })
  return value
}

iterate(data.values,0)
console.log(data)
```